# Compiling GWT in IntelliJ

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

Recently I've decided to package the GWT application of my company using Intellij. IntelliJ compiled the GWT application without errors but its not going thru the permutations and the war does not contain everything its needed. Maven does the job wihout problems. My GWT facets are checked on "project structure -> Facets". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Open the "project struture" window and select "Artifacts" from the Project Setings list. In the list of artifacts, select your project artifact (if there is none, add one).

Select the output layout tab and add "GWT compiler output".

This will invoke the GWT compiler in case you select: Build -> Build Artifacts.

Also, you can use the GWT maven plugin.

[image: Project structure window]

Comment: It's already there. I figured that if I delete the project and check it out again intellij will go thru permutations on the first build.